# WooCommerce - Display variation custom field value

Tags: php, functions, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm using the following function to add a custom field called "price_1_50" to each product variation:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_variation_options_pricing', 'bbloomer_add_custom_field_to_variations', 10, 3 );
function bbloomer_add_custom_field_to_variations( $loop, $variation_data, $variation ) {
woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
    'id' => 'price_1_50[' . $loop . ']',
    'class' => 'short',
    'label' => __( 'Price 1-50:', 'woocommerce' ),
    'value' => get_post_meta( $variation->ID, 'price_1_50', true )
));
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_save_product_variation', 'bbloomer_save_custom_field_variations', 10, 2 );
function bbloomer_save_custom_field_variations( $variation_id, $i ) {
    $price_1_50 = $_POST['price_1_50'][$i];
    if ( isset( $price_1_50 ) ) update_post_meta( $variation_id, 'price_1_50', esc_attr( $price_1_50 ) );
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'bbloomer_add_custom_field_variation_data' );
function bbloomer_add_custom_field_variation_data( $variations ) {
    $variations['price_1_50'] = '<div class="woocommerce_custom_field">Price 1-50: 
<span>'get_post_meta( $variations[ 'variation_id' ], 'price_1_50', true ) . '</span></div>';
return $variations;
}
```

In functions.php i've wrote a function which replaces the product price with the custom field "price_1_50" but i think i can't get the variation ID to display the custom field in the frontend.

I've tried

```
var price = <?php echo get_post_meta( $variation_id, 'price_1_50', true ); ?>;
```

```
var price = <?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'price_1_50', true ); ?>;
```

```
$arrvariations = $variation->get_children (); $price_1_50 = get_post_meta( $arrvariations, 'price_1_50', true ); echo $price_1_50;
```

The only way to get a result in the frontend in single product page is if i write the variation ID.

```
var price = <?php echo get_post_meta( 10652, 'price_1_50', true ); ?>;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I've managed to solve this. This is how i finally created variations custom field:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_after_variable_attributes', 'variation_settings_fields', 10, 3 );

add_action( 'woocommerce_save_product_variation', 'save_variation_settings_fields', 10, 2 );

function variation_settings_fields( $loop, $variation_data, $variation ) {
    woocommerce_wp_text_input( 
        array( 
            'id'          => 'price_1_50[' . $variation->ID . ']',
            'class'       => 'price_1_50',
            'type'        => 'text',  
            'label'       => __( 'Price | Product amount: 1-49', 'woocommerce' ), 
            'placeholder' => '',
            'desc_tip'    => 'true',
            'description' => __( 'Enter price for product amount 1-49 (if available)', 'woocommerce' ),
            'value'       => get_post_meta( $variation->ID, 'price_1_50', true )
        )
    );
}

function save_variation_settings_fields( $post_id ) {
    $text_field = $_POST['_price_1_50'][ $post_id ];
    if( ! empty( $text_field ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'price_1_50', esc_attr( $text_field ) );
    }
}
```

And this is how i got the desired result in frontend (based on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47646939/how-to-get-woocommerce-variation-id)

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'     => 'product_variation',
    'post_status'   => array( 'private', 'publish' ),
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'orderby'       => 'menu_order',
    'order'         => 'asc',
    'post_parent'   => get_the_ID() // get parent post-ID
);
$variations = get_posts( $args );

foreach ( $variations as $variation ) {

    $variation_ID = $variation->ID;

    $product_variation = new WC_Product_Variation( $variation_ID );

    get_post_meta( $variation_ID , 'price_1_50', true );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following:

```
$post = $wp_query->post;
global $post;
```

Then use:

```
$price = get_post_meta($post->ID,'price_1_50',true);
echo $price;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I've tried that but still doesn't work. I have also tried with global $product and global $woocommerce with no result.

Comment: What is your `wp_query` code in functions.php?

Comment: Actually it's a script inside a function that displays the product total price and it's something like this : var product_total_price= parseFloat(price * $price_1_50)

Comment: Is this outside of the loop? If so that is why get_the_id isn't working. I've amended my answer above so maybe try that.